# Modify pointer attribute

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a unordered_map.

```
unordered_map <string,Object> m_map;
```

when I create a new Object and insert it into the unordered map.

```
m_object = new Object();
m_materials["Example"]=*m_object;
```

Its posible to modify the m_object that is into the unordered map without accessing to the unordered_map?

Thanks

Comment: Why is accessing the map a problem? Usually its very fast.

Comment: "When I create a new Object and insert ***a copy of it*** into the unordered map ***before leaking the original Object***."

Comment: @ScepticalJule I think that It´s more efficient without accessing the map, I´m wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not storing pointers to objects but directly objects, so you need to access the instance which is stored in the `unordered_map` node.

When you do

```
m_materials["Example"]=*m_object;
```

The dereference operators will turn the pointer into the real object which is the copied inside the `unordered_map`. You even get a leak unless you do `delete m_object`.

With pointers you would be able to do the following:

```
MyObject *object = new Object();
unordered_map<string, MyObject*> mapping;
mapping["foobar"] = object;

object->attribute = something_else;
assert(mapping["foobar"]->attribute == something_else);
```

In this case you store pointers to objects, so until you have the address of a valid `MyObject` instance stored in the map, you can modify it and the modification reflects to the object inside the map (since there's no real object, but just a pointer to the same object).

Answer (score 0):

The map contains a copy of the `Object` pointed to by `m_object`.  So, no, you cannot modify the `Object` that was inserted into the map via the `m_object` pointer.  Not unless the `Object` class has some kind of sharing semantics.